# URL for delete a record from MongoDB using nodejs is not giving any result

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

```
const sdeleteRecord=("/delete/:studentEmail", async (req, res) => {
const paramsValue = req.params['studentEmail'];
console.log(paramsValue);
const filter = { studentEmail: paramsValue };
console.log(filter);
const doc = await studentInfo.findOneAndDelete(filter)
console.log('doc');
res.send('successfully deleted');})
```

In route file the code is added like this.

```
router.post("/delete/:studentEmail",sdeleteRecord);
```

when i run through postman app it displays output as successfully deleted. But in browser, when i use http:localhost:8000/delete/subhakrishh@gmail.com,It is not showing any error in the webpage and also not giving any output as expected. Simply showing processing. kindly help me to resolve. I feel something wrong with the URL I use. Unable to understand. kindly guide me to resolve it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "not working as expected" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be that you are using POST rather than GET. Get only relies on a URL, while POST uses a body. Try making this a GET request instead and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: thanks. ya.it works when i use get instead of post. thanks for your time